# Select only parent data and not child data using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have lazy loading enabled for a database-first Entity Framework model. For this example, I will use the tables State and City, where the City table is a child table for the State table (connected via a foreign key).

When using the following query:

```
from State in DBEntity.State
where State.StateId == 1
select State
```

I get the State object, which includes a List of City objects. This list is populated when using the query above. In some circumstances, I need just the list of States and do not want the Cities. In these cases, getting the child data (cities) would significantly decrease performance. In some other circumstances, I do need all child data even if the performance is slow.

How can I achieve the following:

- Get all State and City data in one function
- Get just the State data and not the City data (no child data) in another function

Comment: I'd recommend to disable lazy loading model-wide, and to use eager loading (`Include()`) when necessary. If desired, you can enable lazy loading in individual context instances.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `City` property on `State` virtual.

Per [EntityFrameworkTutorial.net](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx):

> Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not defined as virtual.

This will only load the list of `City` objects if you use an `include()` statement or attempt to access them after loading your `State`.

Comment: Is this the correct answer for database-first approach as well? I usually do not change auto-generated classes since they might be overwritten the next time I update the model. If I change the auto-generated State class and make the City property virtual, would that change survive a model update/refresh?